# I want make an apk can set status bar color for all other app

Tags: android, statusbar

I want make an apk can set status bar color for all other app. Mean I don't want other app change the status bar color. Ex: in gmail, status bar will have red color, but I want just black. Is it possible?

Comment: you can't tell other apps how they should look, it is not your permission.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, what you are asking is difficult. I've only seen it done for rooted phones so you can probably go that route. Or you could look at an app such as Substratum which manages the skins of the android and it's apps, for ideas.

Start researching how to do this and ask for assistance on StackOverflow.